# get the result for third dropdown by passing the selected dropdown values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am showing the dropdowns based on the above selected dropdowns. I want the result in third dropdown. For that I am writing the `sql` query in `php` and writing the change event in jquery but i am unable to get the result. I am stuck up there

My jquery looks like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent_cat,#city").change(function(){
        $.get('loadlocation.php?city=' + $(this).val() , function(data) {
          $("#sub_cat").html(data);

        });
    });
});
```

parent_cat and city are from selected values

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<label for="city">city</label>
<select name="city" id="city">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent1)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['city']; ?>"><?php echo $row['city']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
```

And my php file loadlocation.php is

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    $parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT  table_place_detail.post_title FROM table_terms, table_place_detail, table_post_locations
    WHERE  table_place_detail.post_location_id =    table_post_locations.location_id AND  table_place_detail.default_category =  table_terms.term_id AND  table_post_locations.city =  '$city' AND table_terms.name =  '$parent_cat'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<option value='$row[post_title]'>$row[post_title]</option>";
    }
?>
```

I want to fetch the values of parent_cat, city to loadlocation.php but i am not able to get those values. I want to load the two values and get the query excecuted and the values should shown in 3rd dropdown as below can any one help this issue

```
<label>Vendors List 1</label>
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
```

Comment: echo "<option value='{$row[post_title]}'>{$row[post_title]}</option>"; use this instead of yours

Comment: Hi sunil, thanku i have changed how can i write the the jquery to load the values in to the php file query and get the result.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia that doesn't make any difference...is optional syntax

Comment: What does "not able to get those values" mean? Don't you get `parent_cat` and `city`? Have you tested `loadlocation.php` by loading in your browser, e.g. `http://localhost/loadlocation.php?parent_cat=foo&city=bar`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche in jquery function when there is only city value is submitting into the loadcity.php and get the value of city when the user is selected in dropdown and $city variable in the query is excecuted by taking the value. Here i want both the parent_cat and city values should be excecuted in the query . i am not understanding where i get wrong

Comment: @user3124779 I don't understand that. Do you have two PHP scripts, `loadlocation.php` and `loadcity.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things stand out

- You send only one value, `?city=`
- According to the manual [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), you can send additional parameters as a plain object. This means, you don't need to build a query string, but can pass `parent_cat` and `city` separately, e.g.

  ```
  $.get("loadlocation.php",
        { parent_cat: $('#parent_cat').val(), city: $('#city').val() },
        function(data) {
            $('#sub_cat').html(data);
        });
  ```

And finally, the mandatory hint at each `mysql_*` page

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_query()
> - PDO::query()

Comment: Thanku Soo much Olaf
got it